# What's a better way to design this form?

Tags: forms, controls

This is by Doodle, a neat little service for coordination of meetings (no affiliation etc.). Once an invitation is sent out to participants, they get this form.

What, um, ticks me about it is the part I marked. 
[image]

Specifically, I see two issues with it:

1. They changed the functionality of what's probably the single most standard control in the world - a regular checkbox.
2. They notify the users of this change in a way that doesn't seem to be very elegant or efficient.

What would be a better way to solve this form?

Comment: just curious about the useful of this "if need be" option cause I've never see it before: for what scenarios is useful in real life? I thought that if the meeting is really necessary, one could just select the days when it's not impossible to go and if it's not necessary one could deliberately choose less options than the ones where one's actually available, so what's the use?

Comment: When a bunch of people are trying to agree on a date to have a meeting, some people do feel the need to prioritize. This is a way to have basic priorities, where they can say "dates X and Y are fine, but I can also manage Z if absolutely necessary, although I'd rather not".

Comment: Thanks, I got it. And how they figure out the best option to set the meeting after voting when (for example) the sum of "if necessary" for one date is quite higher than the sum of the plain "I can assist" for other date?

Comment: now related to the question, how is state reflected nowadays in doodle? I mean, how can one differentiate between an "if needed" and "yes" option after they are select?

Comment: @AlejandroVeltri The final decision is up to the organizer, it's not automatic. "If needed" is reflected by having a yellow "(v)" icon inside the checkbox, the same as seen in the instruction above but in yellow.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to have singular controls per action, I wonder how many people read the action suggestion at the top?

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgoClw.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Although I'm cautious of drop-boxes with options, there's only 3 and it allows a clear choice for each date to be displayed.

Answer (score 2):

I don't usually advocate for modals but I can see it being handy here.

I think, specifically for the view mentioned in the screenshot, a modal would do wonders.

- Simply have a <kbd>Respond</kbd> or <kbd>Mark As</kbd> button for each event.
- A click brings up a *response modal* which has the responses to pick from.
- If the click count bothers you, add **Next** and **Previous** buttons for making navigation easier. The user won't have to exit the modal to switch between events.
- If the options to pick from are under 5 in number, use radio buttons for the responses (which would work better than a dropdown as [DarrylGodden](https://ux.stackexchange.com/users/34364/darrylgodden) mentioned)

Answer (score 0):

I understand that this applies to voting during the time of the meeting?

I think good solution will be condensation two rows of table into one with graphic symbol and CTA on the pattern:

This will solve the presentation of the number of participants and it will facilitate clickthrough and behavioral understanding at the level of intuition

**Can the system read the name from the API?**

if yes do not need the input with the name

if no it's should be validated for the name

[image]

Comment: I don't think that's it, I'm sure I've received one of these from a co-worker in the past, I believe a single click is attendance and a double is 'if you need me,' they're changing a binary tick-box to have a tri-state, my suspicion is to save space as, in Vitaly's example, there's only 2 participants, but if you had 50, it's quite a long form and clunky.

Comment: I realizes that this solution is limited to true / false, Though yours extends functionalit and presents a wider context. However, if you set a meeting time, there may be 
too many factors to decide when the meeting will take place .

Comment: I believe the meeting time is set in the invite, not requested,

Comment: ok, I thought it was about planning a meeting in time for which the most participants will vote :)

Comment: It is, but it is set by the requestor, the participants merely indicate which is best for them, hence the checkbox.

Comment: I'm  not sure what the difference between your two versions is :). This is a poll offering a number of meeting options, and the participants mark their availability for each of the options.